# migrated website; changed DNS a record IP to point to new site location. now errors

Tags: php, dns, migration, database-connection, a-records

I inherited a website. boss wants it migrated to new host. I moved over all the files and created the new database. I pointed the DNS "a record" to the new IP address and I'm receiving errors:

Warning: include(includes/configure.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/32/11410732/html/qaausa/buick/buick-encore.php on line 4

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/configure.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/chroot/home/content/32/11410732/html') in /home/content/32/11410732/html/qaausa/buick/buick-encore.php on line 4

I received these errors for every "include" method in the file.
could it be the database connection?
The php files in question are indeed in the locations that they are supposed to be in.

Edit*** It was the file paths. I went in to each file and corrected the file paths to reflect the new host's file system...

Comment: It can't be the db, it doesn't find the file, have you changed server? The enviroment is different how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors are due to the change of hosting environment, specifically the php.ini file and the directory structure.
On the previous server the php.ini file would have been configured to show no errors or only say fatal errors as expected in a production environment, rather than warnings showing etc. You need to locate your php.ini file and change the `error_reporting` line to something like so:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
```

Potentially these errors existed on the previous server, but as the errors were set to not show, you would have been none the wiser.

Secondly look at all instances of require and include and check to see how the paths are referenced, a variable could potentially be in use and as the directory structure has changed due to the new host, the includes need to represent this. This is the best advice I can give without further information on the os etc of the previous and new server etc.